# How to migrate from flash to adobe air iOs and android?

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a few projects with flash that i'd like to turn into apps for mobiles, I started reading adobe air and i've noticed that it uses back some things like inframe action script, something that I have not done since as2.

Is there a way to load scripts and classes like a normal flash file?

If I have a noncomplicated swf, is there a way to migrate it easily into adobe air for android and iOs?.

I've been struggling to find examples of adobe air projects, does anyone have a tip for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy.  I have converted 30 games to run on iOS and Android.  The biggest problem was that they were in AS2 and had to be converted to AS3 first.  If your uncomplicated swf projects are in AS3, and developed using Flash Pro, then just change the publishing output from swf for a web page to iOS pr Android.  Android would be easier to start because you don't need to get an Apple developer account, create a certificate and provisioning file.  With Android you can create a certificate right in Flash Pro.  You test publish on your pc or mac first.  When you are ready to test on a device you create an ipa (iOS) or .apk (Android).

Yes, there are a lot of screen sizes out there.  But you know how you can create Flash in a web page so that it will resize with the page and keep its aspect ratio? Well its the same on mobile - it will resize to fit whatever mobile screen it displays on.  Most likely your game is in landscape orientation. Just keep it that way and test it on whatever device you have (an iPad would be good because that aspect ratio or 1024 x 768).  Actually, we kept the stage to 736 x 552 and that fit on any screen out there.  On tall (wide) screens like the iPhone 5 & 6 you will have space on the sides, but so what.

Just give it a shot and you'll see how easy it is to write an app for both platforms at the same time.  And you don't even have to own a Mac (you only need one to upload your completed app to the store, but you can rent time on one and log into it for 10 minutes to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

There's no "how to" when porting a Flash project to Ios or Android. It's the same technology so it's compatible in theory. You can simply compile and publish and you'll get a Ios and Android app in most cases. Now there's 3 major problems that probably 100% of Flash projects will face when publishing for mobile and in probably 99% of cases those problems might imply recreating the whole thing from scratch.

First problem: Sizing and Density. So many phones/tablets sizes and density, chances are your Flash project doesn't have a single line of code dealing with that and as a result your app won't display correctly across any mobile devices. You'll have to put together a big piece of code to handle that and make sure it doesn't break anything in the original project. Good Luck with that.

Second Problem: Performance and memory management, I'm yet to see a Flash project that doesn't systematically waste CPU and memory constantly. That's no problem for a Flash project except when publishing for mobile: can we still waste CPU power? NO, can we still waste memory: NO. You'll have to go through your entire Flash project and optimize everything to not waste CPU and memory. Once again Good Luck with that.

Third Problem: assets. Did you use a bunch of MovieClip here and there? Well no more on mobile unless you want your app to lag and drain the battery down and make the user experience as bad as possible. All assets have to be optimized for mobile, the right asset, the right type, the right size or else ... lag and bad experience. Here again Good Luck with that.

And this is just a small run down of the problems you'll be facing. You will spend probably hundreds of hours trying to port that Flash project to mobile and at the end it will still be running bad anyway. Chances are you should just start over.

EDIT:

Simple Guidelines:

- render mode: usually "gpu" (very efficient with bitmap) but "cpu" is also possible (you get more CPU power but less bitmap display efficiency) and also "direct" if you want to use Stage3D (more complicated).
- Display: usually bitmap and only rarely vector. Don't oversize them and don't undersize them either. Reuse as much as possible (saves memory and battery)
- Handling sizes and density: scaling your content is the easy way but not the less efficient one, as long as your bitmaps are of good quality you should be able to get a good resolution in most density and size. Because there's so many different sizes out there you'll decide if you want your content to fit any size or to display as much as possible while filling the side gaps. AIR/Flash has no built-in system for handling that so you'll have to create your own or to find something open source out there that can do that. Basically you have a content that is n x n and it needs to display on a mobile screen that is n x n, you calculate the scale factor and scale your content and center it.
- perf, memory, battery: reuse object as much as possible. If there's a bitmap that you'll use often don't get rid of it just reuse it. If you reuse you don't need more CPU, don't need more memory and don't need more battery.
- how to get perf: displaying something and running code, that's the 2 things that will slow down the app so optimize both and test often. Maybe reducing the quality of some bitmap will boost your perf. maybe optimizing your code in some places will get you a few more fps, etc. This is a per project try and test.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any really useful guide about starting projects for air? good practices, handling mobile sizes? The adobe guides are not really useful. I need to make a simple game with a few simple buttons, and I'm not sure how to optimize it for mobile performance.